# How do I get the value of useState from component A to component B

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state-management

I'm relatively new to JS and React as a whole, I delved into React and started making some projects with Django backend. I have a list of items in the ProductList component in react,

I have a state `cart` I want to access from ProductList to Cart component. the Idea is when the add to cart button is clicked, the item gets added to cart array of objects
How do I get the values added to Cart component? also if there is a better way to do this a suggestion would be nice.

**ProductList component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './css/ProductList.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
// import { CartContext } from './CartContext'


function ProductList(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cart, setItem] = useState([])

    

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/shop')
            .then(res => {
                setProducts(res.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }, [])

    const addToCart = (item) =>{
        setItem([...cart, item])
    }

    // const { item } = useContext(CartContext)

    return (
        <>
            {
                products.map((product) => (
                    <div className="Box" key={product.id}>
                        {product.items.map((item) => (
                            <div key={item.id} >
                                <img src={item.attachment.attachment} alt={product.name} />
                                <h5>{item.color}</h5>
                                <button className="add" onClick={()=>{addToCart(item)}}>Add to cart</button>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        
                        <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`}><h4>{product.name}</h4></Link>
                        <p>{product.description}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
            }

        </>
    )
}

export default ProductList
```

**Cart component.**

```
import React from 'react'


function Cart(props) {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: best to use a state management system like `redux`

Comment: Just did a bit of googling, the configuration looks scary... Would give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: yup, but that's the industry standard way to share state between components. There is other simpler way using `callback to parent` and then pass via props, this soon becomes very messy and difficult to manage.

Comment: there is also the option of useContext, a bit simpler than  redux and for this specific scenario can do the thing:https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: using redux will be an overkill in this scenario . you can just use `context` api from react .

Comment: I'm reading the document for use Context, it's seems confusing. How do I get the array out of the ProductList component to Cart component. Looks damn impossible with useContext and createContext.

Answer (score 0):

there are already good opinions in the comments, so i actually wrote the code simply.

child component (Cart) should avoid changing the state of parent component (ProductList). so, in the parent component, the method for adding product is passed as props. after that, the child component calls the method to add it.

the above solution is what Rajdeep Debnath said in the comments.

---

**ProductList**

```js
export default function ProductList() {
  //...

  return (
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <Cart key={product.id} product={product} addToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
  );
}
```

---

**Cart**

```js
export default function Cart({ product, addToCart }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
      <div>{product.id}</div>
      <div>{product.content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Context way of solving the problem

But please be aware you use context only ->  **If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels, the component composition is often a simpler solution than context.**

```
// cart.context.js
import * as React from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext();

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);
  
  const contextValue = {
    cart: cart,
    addToCart: (product) => {
      setCart(c => [...c, product])
    }
    // add any functions that update the cart here like addToCart
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
  );
}


// Below is a simple hook that gives you the `contextValue` above

function useCart() {
  const context = React.useContext(CartContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useCart must be used within a CartProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { CartProvider, useCart };
```

Then wrap your nearest parent for both `Cart` and `ProductList` with below

Assuming it is `App` but try to wrap the nearest parent

```
import { CartProvider } from '...cart.context.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      // ... App component return goes here (wrap)  
    </CartProvider>
  )
}
```

Now you can use the `useCart` in all the child components like this

```
import { useCart } from '...cart.context.js';

export default function ProductList() {
 const { addToCart }  = useCart();

  return (
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <Cart key={product.id} product={product} addToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { useCart } from '...cart.context.js';

function Cart(props) {
 const { cart }  = useCart();

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: If you are familiar with `rxjs and Observables` ->  can also solve your current problem.